# Not able to join a string properly in python

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I am not able to join a string properly.

**Here is the code:**

```
def mub(s):
 count = 1
 for i in range(len(s)):
     words = s[i] * count 
     list_of = list(words)
     print('-'.join(list_of),end='')
     count+=1
mub('Abcd')
```

it gives me this as output :
ab-bc-c-cd-d-d-d

but my desired output is this:
a-bb-ccc-dddd

I think the mistake is after for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to keep list of string you want to join with `-`. For example:

```
def mub(s):
 count = 1
 to_join = []
 for i in range(len(s)):
     to_join.append(s[i] * count)
     count+=1
 print('-'.join(to_join))

mub('abcd')
```

Prints:

```
a-bb-ccc-dddd
```